# I want to run tensorFlow JS model in a framework that have frontend and backend what are you recommendations?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

Currently we have a web app (single html page with a script tag) which runs a TensorFlow JS model, that we trained using teachable machine website.

The code runs correctly, and we can see the predictions.

Now, and according to our knowledge transferring into a framework that have frontend and backend will be better, so:

1. We will transfer the logic there.
2. And to add a database to store the prediction.

Which solution you suggest us to procced with to achieve our target in the most suitable way, currently we are thinking about (react JS + node JS) but we still can’t determine if it’s the right option.

Answer (score 0):

The React + Node.js stack you're looking for is implemented in [Remix](https://remix.run/) (not affiliated). You are able to define both backend and frontend logic in the same  file which is then compiled for both the browser and Node:

```js
export async function action({request}) {
  // Server side
  const form = await request.formData();
}

export default function Home() {
  // Client side
  return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```